# Etiquetas de valores en gráfico matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un gráfico de barras al que deseo añadir una etiqueta con el valor de la barra y, aunque he conseguido hacerla aparecer en el gráfico, no consigo formatearla correctamente.

Me gustaría que el formato de los números fuera más legible y centrarlos verticalmente respecto a las barras.

Este es el resultado que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y con este código he puesto las etiquetas:

```
#Añado las etiquetas con el número de votos en el gráfico gvot.
#Con el bucle for recorro las barras del gráfico y coloco la etiqueta con el número de votos al lado de cada barra. La lista que contiene los votos se compone de números enteros.
        v = 0
        for i in gvot.patches:
            gvot.annotate(votos[v], xy = (i.get_width(), i.get_y()), fontsize = 14)
            v = v+1
```

Comment: He añadido una respuesta. Si no funciona, por favor, añade un ejemplo completo, no solo una porción del código, para poder trabajar sobre el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

En `annotate` puedes usar las *keywords* `ha` y `va` (o `horizontalalignment` y `verticalalignment`, respectivamente). En tu caso, sin tener el código completo para probar, quizá se podría solucionar añadiendo `va='center'` de modo que quedaría así:

```py
#Añado las etiquetas con el número de votos en el gráfico gvot.
#Con el bucle for recorro las barras del gráfico y coloco la etiqueta con el número de votos al lado de cada barra. La lista que contiene los votos se compone de números enteros.
        v = 0
        for i in gvot.patches:
            gvot.annotate(votos[v], 
                          xy=(i.get_width(), 
                          i.get_y()), 
                          fontsize=14,
                          va='center')
            v = v+1
```

Referencias:

- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Annotation
- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py